# How can we replace contact number at footer in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Just suggest me to replace a phone number at footer in Magento 1.9.

Where can we replace, can someone give me the path directions.

Comment: What you want to change in Footer? Can you please share screen shot or link of the website?

Answer (score 0):

system>configuration>design>footer you can change here the footer details here if you want to change the store information then General> store information